# Extract type at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a Type name  being passed as an input .
    "MyApp.Modules.Common.contact".

Using `Activator.CreateInstance` how do I construct this type in the method that I'm using.
if I do it like this

```
Type typ = Type.GetType("MyApp.Modules.Common.contact")
```

the typ is always null. How do I fix this. Please help.

Comment: where declare this type? possibly before you need load assembly with this type. Also check type name for a typo or something like

Comment: "If the assembly has not been saved to disk when GetType is called, the method returns null.", lots of other reasons in the remarks of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too, do any of these reasons apply?

Comment: Is it in same assembly? If not try: `Type typ = Type.GetType("MyApp.Modules.Common.contact, "+assemblyName)`

Answer (score 5):

If you provide just the type name, `Type.GetType` will look in the currently-executing assembly, and `mscorlib` - but that's all. If you need to access a type in a different assembly, then either you need to get the assembly name in the type as well, e.g. `"MyApp.Modules.Common.contact, MyApp.Modules.Common"` (if the assembly name is `"MyApp.Modules.Common"` - or if you have an `Assembly` reference, you can use [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you have no information about what assembly you should look in, but you're confident that the assembly *has* been loaded, you could potentially use [`AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the assemblies, and then look through each of those in turn, calling `Assembly.GetType` until you find a match.

I would encourage you to look at the design of where how the type information is being passed around though - ideally make sure that the assembly information *is* available.

Comment: when I do type.GetType(" MyApp.Modules.Common.contact") it returns me a system.runtimetype only

Comment: @Jayaraman: Do you mean `Type.GetType`? It's really unclear what you mean at this point.